# json return in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I have a controller that returns a JSON string as below

```
$response = Response::json(array("success"=>"true","token"=>$token));
```

the return value is `{"success":"true","token":{}}` but when I put a static value like

```
$response = Response::json(array("success"=>"true","token"=>"12345"));
```

the return value is correct `{"success":"true","token":"12345"}`

The variable `$token` is generated as it is inserted into the database, but not returned properly.

Token is generated from webpatser UUID using: Uuid:generate();

***Question:*** How can I fix that?

---

**UPD:**

The `var_dump($token)` results:

```
["string":protected]=> string(36) "d0c95650-3269-11e4-a55e-15cdb906eead"
```

**UPD 2:**

```
$response = Response::json(array("success"=>"true","token"=>$token[0]));

returns {"success":"true","token":NULL}
```

Tried changing the value of $token to other variables such that

```
$test = "test";
```

then

```
$response = Response::json(array("success"=>"true","token"=>$test));
```

return `{"success":"true","token":"test"}`

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$token` with [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var-dump) ? What have it shown?

Comment: Just try with first element of $token : 
$response = Response::json(array("success"=>"true","token"=>$token[0]));

Comment: Check the value of $token, it's may be empty

Comment: @HAL9000 the var_dump($token) results in this: ["string":protected]=>
  string(36) "d0c95650-3269-11e4-a55e-15cdb906eead"

Comment: @vikramjain I tried your suggestion, im getting NULL. see updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$token` variable contains an object, that have value as a [`protected`](http://php.net/protected) member, which json encoder can not access to.

There probably should be the way to get it with some getter methods, like `$token->getValue()` or something similar. In such case you need to change your response to

```
$response = Response::json(array("success"=>"true","token"=>$token->getValue()));
```

If you could provide the class methods by [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/get-class-methods), I may be able to suggest further.

As a ***workaround*** (it is not actually the preferred way to do this) you may try to use [reflection](http://php.net/reflection):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

class A {
    protected $test = 'xxx';

    public function change(){
        $this->test = 'yyy';
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->change();

$class    = new ReflectionClass(get_class($a));
$property = $class->getProperty('test');

$property->setAccessible(true); // "Dark "magic"

echo $property->getValue($a); // "Dark magic"
?>
```

Shows:

```
yyy
```

So in your code it might be like this:

```
$class    = new ReflectionClass(get_class($token));
$property = $class->getProperty('string');

$property->setAccessible(true);

$token = $property->getValue($token);

$response = Response::json(array("success"=>"true","token"=>$token));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide that via a getter method in the class itself.

So in the class:

```
public function getData()
{
  return $this->string;
}
```

And in your program:

```
$token->getData();
```

Comment: Tried this and the value is still null. The problem seems to be in the uuid generator as I tried passing other variables as the value for token and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

User foreach for $token and get the value from it. Assign it in some variable and use it in your response.

exa.

```
$my_tocken = "";
foreach ($tocken as $real_tocken){
  $my_tocken = $real_tocken;
}
```

Now build your response as you usually build with your test variables.